# Strcmp in nasm x86_64, registers

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, strcmp

I am trying to implement my own strcmp in asm. Here is the ft_strcmp.s file:

```
global ft_strcmp

section .text
ft_strcmp:
            mov eax, [rdi]
            sub eax, [rsi]
            jne .exit
            cmp byte [rdi], 0 ; if s1 end
            je .exit
            cmp byte [rsi], 0 ; if s2 end
            je .exit
            inc rdi
            inc rsi
            jmp ft_strcmp
.exit:
            ret
```

For the first letter it's OK:
char *s1 = "Hello World"
char *s2 = "Jdllo World"
The result is 1. (**0000 0001**)

The problem is that when I am trying to compare these strings:

char *s1 = "Hello World"

char *s2 = "Hdllo World"

The result in RAX is NOT 1, but 256. (**0000 0001** 0000 0000)

Another example:

char *s1 = "Hello World"

char *s2 = "Hcllo World"

The result in RAX is NOT 2, but 512. (**0000 0010** 0000 0000)

As you have already understood, the result for third different letters will be:

char *s1 = "Hello World"

char *s2 = "Heklo World"

The result in RAX is NOT 1, but 65 536. (**0000 0001** 0000 0000 0000 0000)

I realize that RAX is incrementing not right, but I can't find the mistake in the code.
So I ask you to help me understand.

Comment: You are loading, and subtracting, 32-bit values from memory using `eax`. As well as the results you're seeing, you risk running past the nul-terminating character. It's just luck that the string lengths, plus the nul-terminator, are multiples of `(4)`, and that the test hasn't been done with `'Hello Worle'`.  Using `al` - the least-significant byte of `eax` - solves that problem, but then requires *sign-extending* `al` to the full 64-bit `rax` return value.

Comment: My last sentence was wrong. Assuming 32-bit `'int'` return value, you only need sign-extend to the 32-bit `eax` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assembly is different than other languages so often times what you *think* may be happening isn't actually what happens. The reason you are getting surprising / incorrect results is because you are subtracting two numbers. You will not immediately see this until you get a debugger(which you should already have if you want to learn / survive in assembly). Let's see what is happening with the help of a debugger.
First let's setup a small `main` and some data:

```
section .data
    str1: db "Hello world",0
    str2: db "Hdllo world",0

section .text
global main

ft_strcmp:
... ; your code here

main:
   nop
   mov rdi, str1
   mov rsi, str2
   
   call ft_strcmp
   nop
```

When execution starts, we load up `rdi` and `rsi` with strings (which is just a sequence of bytes). Important thing here is that `rdi` and `rsi` don't actually "contain" the strings / bytes but point to them i.e., `rdi` and `rsi` contain the address of the location where our strings live.

Next we call the function and here is where the problem starts happening. I am going to focus on these two instructions:

```
    mov eax, [rdi] ;1
    sub eax, [rsi] ;2
```

At instruction `1`, you are moving the string itself into `eax`. `[rdi]` means *get the value at the address which `rdi` has*. It's like dereferencing a pointer. Now, `eax` is 32 bits (4 bytes) in size, so it can only contain 4 bytes. And assuming you have a litte endian system, the order of the bytes will be in reverse, so the value in `eax` will be:

```
eax = 0x6c6c6548
```

if you look at it closely, you will see that it's 4 bytes from `str1`:

```
6c  6c   65  48
'l' 'l' 'e'  'h'
```

Next you subtract this number from the value at address in `rsi` which is:

```
0x6c6c6448
OR
0x6c 6c  64  48
'l' 'l' 'd'  'h'
```

If you subtract these two numbers:

```
0x6c6c6548 - 0x6c6c6448 = 0x100
```

`0x100` in base 10 is 256.

Since the value is non zero, `ZF` (zero flag) will not be set and you will jump to `.exit`.

Hope you now understand what is actually happening.

I highly recommend getting a debugger and using it to debug such issues.

Comment: Dear Waqar, thank you a lot for such a deep explanation! I appreciate your help! Now I see the point and definitely will install debugger to follow register's changes

Comment: Also, if you are stuck in creating logic for something. Go to [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/), write the logic in C/C++, see the assembly output and then do the same in your code. And take a look at the [x86 Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for more resources.

Comment: @mondrew: Note that if you do want to run faster by comparing multiple bytes at once, you need to `bswap eax` / `bswap edx` so the most-significant byte of each input comes from the *earliest* address instead of the latest.  (Then do 64-bit subtraction so there's room for sign bits in the result beyond the unsigned 32-bit numbers, otherwise subtraction can have signed overflow...)  But this is hard to use for `strcmp` because you still have to check every byte for being a terminator.  (related: [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57650895))

Comment: @mondrew: So what you actually do on x86-64 is use SSE2 to do 16 separate byte-compares in parallel with SIMD.  https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/strcmp.S.html is a bit messy to read, with #ifdef to work as strcmp or strcasecmp, and different sizes of unrolled loop to fully ramp up for large inputs.